# PayPal REST Webhooks sending no data

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm trying a simple enough task, just to get PayPal's webhook to send data. So I'm sending various events through from developer.paypal.com's webhook simulator, which is successfully contacting the server, but which is sending blank data.  The code to check what data is sent is

```
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO paypal_webhook_tests (`datetime`,`data`) VALUES ('$datetime','SOMETHING PASSING THROUGH')");

foreach ($_POST as $key=>$val){
    $store = $key.$val;
    $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO paypal_webhook_tests (`datetime`,`data`) VALUES ('$datetime','$store')");
}
```

What ends up happening is that there is nothing in POST at all. What's going on with this?

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially use https://requestb.in/ for creating a request inspector, that could be used as a URL for webhook simulator. This will allow you to make sure you are getting the expected data. Once you are able to confirm that, you should be able to figure out why data is not seen in your webhook URL.